# Notify Changes on external parameter change

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

I need to attach a notify change event to an encapsulated parameter in an external class. I usually would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but I can't edit the external class. What is the right approach for this problem?

Comment: Is it only you who updates instances of that class, or are they updated externally as well?

Comment: You could inherit from that class maybe and then implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your derived version and then use that class instead of the original one?

Comment: @dotNET The property would have to be `virtual` for this to work.

Comment: @MarcelN. The encapsulated parameter only consists of a getter. The parameter is updated only by the external class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be very hard to do. The best option seems to be deriving that class, but you need all properties to be marked `virtual`. When you have no control over the class that seems to be unlikely.

If you are the only one calling that class, you could also create a wrapper that mimics that class' behavior. You could create properties yourself and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You can't get notified on changed to the inner object though.

If that is your best option, you could also implement a implicit conversion operator so you can pass in your class like it was the class you are wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach could be to use a timer which keeps looking at the value of that property every (say) 1 second and notifies you when the property value is not the same as the previous read. Timers use light-weight threads of their own, so this shouldn't be a lot of burden on the resources either. Looking at the tough situation that you're in, this seems to be the only viable option.