# Listening for property value change in third-party .NET library

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I am consuming a third-party library in my .NET C# application. Essentially, the library exposes one method and one property; a pared-down representation of the interface I'm working is:

```
public interface IDisconnect
{
    bool IsDisconnected { get; }

    void Disconnect();
}
```

At some point after calling the method `Disconnect()`, when the disconnect operation completes, the property `IsDisconnected` gets set to `true`. The third-party developer would have made things a lot easier if they'd implemented a `OnDisconnectComplete` event (or similar) for me to subscribe to, but, given that they haven't, are there any elegant ways to listen for a property change in a third-party libraries built in to the .NET framework?

Comment: is the library opensource? Maybe you can extend the interface in your fork - it would be the cleanest way.

Comment: Other idea is to create proxy of the 3rd-party class and add the event, that works only if you can put hands on the class in your code...

Comment: Can you derive from that implemented class and override the property? The method would still update the property, I believe.

Comment: Nope, there are no elegant ways to do that in general. There might be ways in specific cases (like target class implements this property as virtual, and you can inherit and override that, and so on).

Comment: @Divisadero - the library is not open source and the class is sealed.

Comment: @FurkanKambay - the properties are not virtual or abstract.

Comment: Oh it's sealed? That's harsh. I think there's no other way than creating your own method that checks for that value with a loop. Like that answer that was deleted for some reason. You can then create an event and invoke it inside the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notify Changes on external parameter change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260044/notify-changes-on-external-parameter-change)

Comment: Also, a more extreme solution would be modifying the IL code for that library but you or the author _probably_ don't want that.

Comment: @FurkanKambay - As you say, it might have to be a case of looping until the property changes. This is the route I was heading down before asking the question, it just makes me feel a bit dirty! :D

Comment: Think of the property getter as an abstract method (which it is) and then imagine what would be necessary to build a fully general mechanism that could detect a property change in arbitrary code, given that the method could access any value in memory, and vary these between calls if it wanted to. You begin to see the problem of building a mechanism on top of that triggers as soon as reading the property would return a different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information provided there is one very ugly solution, to create notifier class which will get the instance of IDisconnect. Here, you can set the timer to regularly check the value of IsDisconnected and if it changes, raise the event for the IDisconnnect itself. Timer setting is up to you.

Comment: I think, sadly, this might have to be the approach!